# Use regex to filter pandas rows with ~ at beginning AND at end of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to use regular expressions in pandas to filter out rows where there's a `~` at the beginning of the line AND at the end of the line for a given column. For example, take the following pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'line': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'Unit': ['LF', 'LS~', '~~SF', 'CY', '~SF~', 'PC', '~~', '~LF', '~PC~']})
```

Here's what I want for output:

```
df[df.Unit.str.contains(MY_EXPRESSION, regex=True)]
   line Unit
0     1   LF
1     2   LS~
2     3   ~~SF
3     4   CY
5     6   PC
7     8   ~LF
```

What I've tried so far:

1. MY_EXPRESSION = '^[^~].*[^~]$'

This filters anything with a ~ at the beginning OR end of the string. I want to only filter out rows with a `~` at the beginning AND end of the string.

2. MY_EXPRESSION = '^([^~])(.*)([^~])$'

This also filters out rows with a ~ at the beginning OR end of a string. Again, I want to only filter out rows with a `~` at the beginning AND end of the string.

What is the regular expression that I need (i.e., `MY_EXPRESSION` in the example) in order to filter the Dataframe the desired way?

I'm using pandas v.0.23.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.match`

```
df[~df.Unit.str.match('^~.*~$')]

   Unit  line
0    LF     1
1   LS~     2
2  ~~SF     3
3    CY     4
5    PC     6
7   ~LF     8
```